# Patching process differences (OSX vs Debian / CE vs EE)

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, patches, enterprise-1.13

We've got 2 Magento sites, one is CE 1.7.0.2 and the other is EE 1.13.1.0. I can apply all of the CE site patches locally on my Mac without issue. When I try to apply the patches against the same codebase sitting on a Debian server, they fail with many "Hunk x FAILED at x" errors. I've compared the files against a vanilla Magento 1.7.0.2 installation using FileMerge and there aren't any differences. This is starting with the chronologically first patch and occurs on every patch through the latest 7405 and 7616 patches. That rules out the problem being that previous patches weren't applied.

**HOWEVER**

I'm not having issues applying the EE versions of these patches to our EE site in our Debian environment.

Any idea what the problem could be? At first I thought it could be the patch scripts detecting some kind of hidden line ending or character return differences that are missed/ignored on OS X. Finding that I'm not having the same issue on the EE site kind of squashes that theory.

Comment: Can you check if you have present in both systems the `app/etc/applied.patches.list` file?

Comment: I do, and I can tell which patches have been applied by running the scripts and seeing it in the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK just for the record, line endings were set to Windows-style. I changed line endings to Unix-style for the site and all patches applied successfully.